# What is the difference between these two questions? Why was one closed and the other left open?

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between [these](https://serverfault.com/questions/169279/how-can-i-choose-between-using-my-isps-dns-or-googles-8-8-8-8) two [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/90908/when-google-dns-or-open-dns-is-a-good-fit)?  Why was one closed and the other left open?  The reason for closure was not duplicate, but that the question was primarily opinion based.  They are from 2009-2010, so they are fairly old, but the closure was from 2014.

I think these two questions are very similar and should have overlapping answers.  They kind of do, to a point.  Yet one was closed for being "primarily opinion based", and the other is not closed.

I am confused by:

- Reason for closure as "primarily opinion based".  The question that was closed was asking for objective measurement methodologies and/or data so that he could compare DNS performance.  I don't understand how that is an opinion.
- The question was closed 5 years after it was asked; it had several answers and an accepted answer.
- The responses to the questions were similar, and there is good reading material on both Q&As, but only one of them were closed.

As for a bit of context, I decided to do a bit of reading about DNS and came across both of them in my internet search.

**PS**

And the first reaction is "Oh we can't have that!" and put the other question on hold?  It's 8 years old!  I doubt the OP is around or will edit it, let alone the answerers update or add to it!

Comment: _"It's 8 years old! I doubt the OP is around or will edit it, let alone the answerers update or add to it!"_ That's not the point. Broken windows is the point. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124635/how-many-questions-on-meta-have-asked-why-cant-i-ask-this-question-when-that

Comment: `And the first reaction is "Oh we can't have that!" and put the other question on hold?` Yeah, well whine about an off-topic question not being closed for some reason.... and what did you expect?  It was closed because you brought attention to the fact that it wasn't, and should have been.  Geez.  No pleasing some people.

Answer (score 9):

They're now both closed.

> Why was one closed and the other left open?

As you pointed out, one was asked in 2009, presumably during a period where that type of question was acceptable, so it was left open. Site rules and expectations change over time, though, and now that question is off-topic. So I've closed it. Oftentimes this is what happens with old, off-topic questions: they sit as-is until someone points them out, at which point they get closed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that both questions are now closed is that they bury the acceptable question "How can I measure DNS performance?" within an unacceptable (by SF standards) question which asks for an opinion based service recommendation.